# añadir id automáticamente con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero saber si es posible añadir id automáticamente a todos los divs que se vayan agregando dentro del div padre, y así mismo estas id se vayan agregando solas en 'let historyElements' de javascript.

solo necesito eso, no quiero cambiar todo el codigo ya que se pierde la funcion que quiero.

```js
let historyElements= [ '','',''];
for (let i=0;i < historyElements.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(openHistory,2000 * i,historyElements[i]);
}
function openHistory(historyName) {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("history");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(historyName).style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
}
.loop{
height: 50%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ddd;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.loop div{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}
#id0{
background-color: #000;
}
#id1{
background-color: #ff0000;
}
#id2{
background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loop">
<div><!--id--></div>
<div><!--id--></div>
<div><!--id--></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si, **si se puede delegar un `evento` a un `elemento` del `DOM` que aun no ha sido creado.**

Yo haría lo siguiente:

> El id debe de ser único

Para que el id sea único puedes crear un contador global e ir aumentadolo a medida que asignas los ids.

```
let cont = 0;
```

Después en el `ready` se genera el ID de los elementos que ya están creados y se añaden al array `let historyElements= [];`:

```
$(".loop > div").each(asignarId);
```

Se delega el evento `DOMNodeInserted`para los `divs` del `.loop` y para los futuros `divs` que aun no han sido creados:

```
$('.loop').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div', asignarId);
```

Función asignarId para no repetir código:

```
function asignarId(){
    $(this).attr("id","divLoop"+cont);
    historyElements.push("divLoop"+cont);
    cont++;
}
```

Y ya está, al crear un nuevo `div` se le añadirá el ID y se añadirá al `array`

> **Nota:** He eliminado del snippet el código irrelevante para esta pregunta.

**Snippet de prueba**

```js
let historyElements= [];
let cont = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".loop > div").each(asignarId);
  $('.loop').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div', asignarId);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".loop").append("<div><!--id--></div>")
    $(".loop").append("<div><!--id--></div>")
    for(let x=0;x<historyElements.length;x++){
      console.log("Array["+x+"]: "+historyElements[x]);
    }
  }, 2000);

  
});

function asignarId(){
    $(this).attr("id","divLoop"+cont);
    historyElements.push("divLoop"+cont);
    cont++;
}
```

```css
.loop >div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop">
  <div><!--id--></div>
  <div><!--id--></div>
  <div><!--id--></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
 let divs = $(".loop div");
 for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){ 
   divs[i].id = `id${i}`;
   console.log(divs[i])
 }
```

```css
    body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    }
    .loop{
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop">
    <div><!--id--></div>
    <div><!--id--></div>
</div>
```